# Neo4j Apoc Periodic Commit Limit is not working

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc, periodicity

I am trying to delete all nodes having degree equal or less than 1 but it is not working.
My query is as follows

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit(" 
MATCH (n:RoadPoint)-[:ROAD_SEGMENT]-(m:RoadPoint) 
WHERE NOT (:Depot)-[:LOCATED_AT]->(n) 
WITH n , COUNT(DISTINCT m) AS c 
WHERE c <= 1 
WITH n limit {limit}
DETACH DELETE n 
RETURN COUNT(*)
", {limit:1000})
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `apoc.periodic.commit()` will be running that exact query over and over each batch, which means that it will be rechecking the same nodes over and over (the ones that didn't meet your criteria) with every batch. You really should be using `apoc.periodic.iterate()` instead. The ideal usage for `apoc.periodic.commit()` is when you don't have to filter and your matches are deleted or change so that they won't get rematched on subsequent batches (such as when deleting nodes of a label or removing the label from labeled nodes)

Comment: Also, what do you mean that this isn't working? How are you expecting the LIMIT to affect this query? All that will be doing is defining the batch size for processing.

Comment: Can you explain what is not working ? Nothing is deleted ? Or just 1000 ? Or something else ?

Comment: my query was not deleting any node, although I have nodes with degree 1. I am using Limit to process nodes batch-wise to avoid error due to limited RAM

Comment: @InverseFalcon, I think apoc.periodic.commit() would be best in my case because I just need to process those nodes which have degree one, in case of  apoc.periodic.iterate() I have to traverse all million nodes in batch,  then checking the degree and deleting. What is your opinion about it?

Answer (score 1):

You can you try this query :

```
CALL apoc.periodic.commit(
  "MATCH (n:RoadPoint)
   WHERE 
    NOT (:Depot)-[:LOCATED_AT]->(n) AND
    size((n)-[:ROAD_SEGMENT]-(:RoadPoint)) <=1
   WITH n LIMIT $limit
   DETACH DELETE n 
   RETURN COUNT(*)", 
  {limit:1000}
)
```

It should works and also be much faster, thanks to the `size` function, that in this case use the degrree statistic that is stored on each nodes.

Comment: solutions look better but in my case edges are both ways, so how I can define distinct because I just have to count edges with unique nodes

Comment: If you really need the distinct you have to use your query, but it means also that you have many relationships between 2 nodes.

Comment: I think I should use distinct because some nodes have bi-directional edges and some nodes have uni-directional. In your query, it will not cover nodes that have degree one but also have bidirectional edges. Yes, I want to use my query, but limit is not working, it returns me 0 updates

Comment: And if you perform the query to search nodes with degree 1, (replace the `with .. limit` by `return ... limit` and  remove what you ahve after), do you have some result ?